# Protractor code to extract multiple paragraph text

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

how to fetch the values of all paragraph (p) at a time ..
for example below is how my inspect view looks like

"testing sample one."


"testing sample two."

and below is my code sample to extract the value of id 'run'

browser.findElement(by.css('[id=run]')).getText()

this just extract the first value or I can modify and get the second value of id.. my need is I need to get both values at one go.. in the same line of code.. could you please advise

Comment: browser.findElements(by.css('[id=run]')).getText() should work ?

Answer (score 0):

Though missing an html-example and a bit more description of what you like to extract, I'll give it a try.

In general you could/should use `element.all(by.css())`, aka `$$()`, instead of `browser.findElements`, except you know exactly, why you use `findElements`.
[Read some details about the difference here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1008).

Then as mentioned in a comment already, there is a `findElements()` ([see API-Doc for findElements() here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.findElements)), returning an array of all values, matching the criteria. Just you can't immediately use `getText()` on it, as you get an array of elements and `getText()` requires a single element ([see API-Doc for getText() here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText)). Therefore you'd need to pass it through some loop.

Without knowing enough context here a small set of ideas to pick from.

```
var allP = new Array();
var allPString = null; //if one long string is desired
//here I'm using now element.all() instead of browser.findElements
var allPEl = $$('p#run'); //equal to element.all(by.css('p[id=run]')); //returns array of all found elements
var allPElBrowser = browser.findElements(by.id('run')); //returns array of all found elements
var i = allPEl.length();
var j = 0;

allPEl.each().getText().then(function(text){  //getAttribute('value') instead of getText(), if getText doesn't work.
    allP.push(text); //add it to Array
    allPString += text+' '; //add to String with a space at the end
    j++; //counter
    if(i === j-1){continueTest()}; //call continuation at the end of last loop, due to asynchronous nature of 'then()'.
});

continueTest = function(){
    allP.toString() //in case of comma separated list from Array is desired
    // here comes the rest of your test case logic
};
```

Note, that I go with the assumption that you need resolved promises, so the content of your `<p>`'s to continue.

If you can continue just with the array of `<p>`-objects, which you later resolve within an `expect()` all you need is `$$('p#id');`.

If the solution doesn't work for you, let me know, what part is still missing or where problems occur.

Comment: This is old question and please ignore